# Mutate PrevState in React (setState with function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Please, explain in detail why this code leads to an error. I have read the article with solution to this problem (const counters = [...prevState.counters];). But why it happens is not clear to me.

When you click the button, you see that counter is incremented two times.
We expect an increment of 1.
Why mutating prevState cause counter incrementing by 2???

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [0, 0],
  };

  clickHandler = index => {
    this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
      let counter = prevState.counters[index];

      const counters = prevState.counters;
      counters[index] = ++counter;
      return {
        counters,
      };
    });
  };
  render() {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map((counter, index) => (
      <Counter
        counter={counter}
        key={index}
        clickHandler={() => this.clickHandler(index)}
      />
    ));
    return <React.Fragment>{counters}</React.Fragment>;
  }
}
```

```
// Counter.js
import React from 'react';

const Counter = ({ counter, clickHandler }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Increment the counter above!</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your `App` in `<React.StrictMode>` ?

Comment: This code from article [https://irensaysblog.netlify.app/web-development/react-setstate]

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - it's because of React.StrictMode combined with mutating state. Funny article title - `React setState: the **Right** Way` 

Comment: @Adam, by the way article is good, it describes the wrong way that lead to errors, and then explain how the problem solve.

Comment: @Ilya - it says `If you work with objects from your state, always copy them to avoid unintended modifications` and then explicitly writes code that does the opposite. No, it's not a "good" article.

Comment: Frankly, I still don't understand how they managed to double the counter using strict mode and mutating state . How wrong way works inside

Comment: `Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: ...` [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). See how it's uage helped indicate that the code is doing something wrong? See how that's **exactly what StrictMode was designed to do**

Comment: You I really helped, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 rule of react: DON'T MUTATE STATE.

```
    this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
      let counter = prevState.counters[index];

      const counters = prevState.counters;
      counters[index] = ++counter; <-- THIS LINE MUTATES counters
      return {
        counters,
      };
    });
```

Should be:

```
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        // return a new array with map, DON't mutate the old one
        counters: prevState.counters.map((c,i) => i === index ? c++ : c);
    }));
```

You are seeing a double increment because:

1. You are using `React.StrictMode` and
2. You are mutating state.

So the point still stands, DON'T MUTATE STATE.

If you use my example with React.StrictMode, you'll see if results in a single increment. It's because the article titled "the right way" actually shows you the **WRONG** way.

If you use React.StrictMode and are noticing logical differences, it's because you are doing something wrong. I mentioned above what you are doing wrong, you are mutating state (like the article shows you).

Never ever ever ever ever mutate state. Always return new objects/arrays, never update existing ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I get it. I know this solution. But the goal of my question is why current counter incremented two times  because prevState=this.state or something else?

Comment: @Ilya - funny how the article says, "the right way" and it mutates state. Despite the fact that it still "works" mutating state leads to hard to find bugs. Never do it. That being said, your code works fine when I put it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d1stpk?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: @Ilya Ah, it's because of `React.StrictMode` like the commenter said: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ojpcr7?file=src%2Findex.js

Comment: @Ilya - combined with the fact that you are mutating state. React.StrictMode should not result in logical changes. If you do see logical changes, it's because you are doing something wrong, which you are, which is the state mutation (thank you to the downvoter).

Comment: you are the best! It's very helpfull information